# MySQL-Count from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. Table `table1` like this

```
specialty     doctor
  1              A
  1              B
  2              A
  2              C
```

Table `table2` like this:

```
specialty     doctor
  1              A
  1              D
  2              C
```

I want to count distinct `doctor` from both the table group by `specialty` and have the output like this

```
specialty      doctor
  1              3
  2              2
```

(specialty 1 has 3 doctors:A, B, D; specialty 2 has 2 doctors: A, C)

Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union` to bring the tables together and then `group by`:

```
select specialty, count(*)
from ((select specialty, doctor from table1) union
      (select specialty, doctor from table2)
     ) t
group by specialty;
```

Note the use of `union` here and *not* `union all`.  You specifically want to eliminate duplicates.